# Is it possible to change the iPhone device name programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to change the device name via the API?
Perhaps this is now available in iOS 5 since it is possible to edit it via settings.

Any lead appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Not in the public API, no. There may well be an undocumented private method to do it, but it's not something you could put in an app going on the store.

Comment: Any links to such API? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Apple would not give 3rd party developers such authority.